# Adb emulator on Android-device

Tags: android, adb

when I enable adb tcpip on my device

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

abd then run a shell

```
adb shell
```

and then run

```
adb devices
```

on that shell it seems that the Android system runs a dummy-device which is associated with the real device:

```
shell@zeroflte:/ $ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

is it possible to start this emulator from the Android system without a USB-connection?

Comment: yes after adb tcpip 5555 run adb connect 192.168.1.device ip and enter

Comment: when i run "adb tcpip 5555" on the device i get "error: device not found" ... the "emulator" must run before i can use any adb commands

Comment: one time you need to connect usb then you can deattach usb

Comment: ... that is what i already described in my question, i cannot ask my customers to connect a debugger to their devices

Comment: if you just want to start "USB debugging" (i.e. `adbd`) on the device in `tcpip` mode without having to connect the device via `USB` first - then say so. The current wording (specially the title) is confusing and misleading. Hence the downvotes

Answer (score 0):

First connect your device by usb.

Then run command on terminal

```
adb tcpip 5555

adb connect <device_ip>
```

Then remove device.

Now you are connected with device. Now you can detach usb cable.

Comment: this is what i've already described, but i want to start it from the device itself, without connecting usb